Comparing dictionary of countries with a column of countries
I have a dictionary/country list which i took from pycountry (list(pycountry.countries)
I am importing a column from excel called CountryNames
i thought by creating 2 for loops, i could then compare to see if my CountryNames is found in the PyCountry list
 import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect 
from googletrans import Translator
import pycountry

   df =  pd.read_excel(r"V1.xlsx")
    input_countries = df['CountryName']
        
        # Ensure the column 'CountryName' exists in the CSV
    if 'Sold To Customer Country' not in df.columns:
            raise ValueError("CountryName' column")
        
    t = list(pycountry.countries)
    
    # loop through column of countries
    for name in input_countries:
        # loop through country name (pycountry)
         for pycountry.name in t:
              # comparison - Show country names 
              if input_countries in t:
                   input_countries
              else:
                   'invalid'enter code here

I want to check to see if a countryName (from the excel column) is in the pycountry list

Not enough code here to be certain about what you're doing. What exactly is pycountry? You will probably find set operations to be useful for this

What's your question ?

Apologies. The original text was cut out (my bad, i've re-added the text

You need two sets. One is a set formed from all entries in the "CountryName" column in the spreadsheet. The other is a combination of all known country names both in their short forms and "official" formats.
Then you just need a simple loop to validate your data.
Something like this should suffice:
import pycountry
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

FILENAME = "V1.xlsx"

def all_names() -> set[str]:
    # all Country objects have a "name" attribute
    return {country.name for country in pycountry.countries} # type: ignore

def all_official_names() -> set[str]:
    s: set[str] = set()
    for country in pycountry.countries:
        # not all Country objects have an "official_name" attribute
        try:
            s.add(country.official_name) # type: ignore
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    return s

def get_df_countries(filename: Path) -> set[str]:
    # construct a set because country names may be duplicated in the spreadsheet column
    # this potentially improves runtime performance when parsing the country names later
    return set(pd.read_excel(filename)["CountryName"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    names = all_names() | all_official_names()
    for country in get_df_countries(Path(FILENAME)):
        status = "valid" if country in names else "invalid"
        print(f"{country} is {status}")

Caveat Emptor
You're limited to 2 forms of country names provided by the pycountry module. Due to typing errors and other subtle variations of country names you may get false negatives from this code

Absolute legend ... it gave me the invalid too. 2 birds with one stone. Thanks
